# Illustrator - Change Stroke Size in Blob Brush Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Whenever I try to make the blob brush tool's weight smaller (ex: .25) it automatically just switches back to size 1 pt. How do I fix this?? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to adjust the stroke size, but the Blob Brush doesn't make a stroke. It makes filled shapes. Use the square bracket keys <kbd>[</kbd> and<kbd>]</kbd> to alter its size instead.

Examples:

The Blob Brush makes a closed path with a fill.

[image]

Using the <kbd>[</kbd> and<kbd>]</kbd> keys to adjust the size

[image]

You can also double click the tool to bring up its options. Note that 1pt is the minimum size available

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so helpful!